# How to convert a byte array to pdf

Tags: c#

I am building an app that modifies a word 2010 document and it should be downloaded as pdf.I write a code to convert word to pdf but it is converting the document I upload not the modified word. How can I convert modified word to PDF.Below is the function which  is not converting modified word.
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)

            {
                string fileNameFromUser = FileUploadControl.FileName;
                var fiFileName = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileNameFromUser);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ms.Write(FileUploadControl.FileBytes, 0, FileUploadControl.FileBytes.Length);

                    using (WordprocessingDocument sDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
                    {

                    }
                    lblMessage.Text = "Dokumenti u ngarkua me sukses!";
                    Session["ByteArray"] = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
                    Session["fileNameFromUser"] = fileNameFromUser;
                }



        }
        byte[] byteArray = (byte[])(Session["ByteArray"]);
        if (byteArray != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ms.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
                    {
                        var body = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                        var lastParagraf = body.Elements<Paragraph>().LastOrDefault();
                        var newParagraf = new Paragraph(

                            new Run(
                                new Text("Perdoruesi:" + " " + User.Identity.Name)));

                        var newParagraf2 = new Paragraph(

                           new Run(
                               new Text("Data dhe ora:" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString())));

                        var newParagraf3 = new Paragraph(

                           new Run(
                               new Text("Kodi unik:" + " " + randomstring(14))));

                        var newParagraf4 = new Paragraph(

                          new Run(
                              new Text("Shifra:" )));

                        lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf);
                        lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf2);
                        lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf3);
                        lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf4);
                    }
                    Session["ByteArray"] = ms.ToArray();
                    lblMessage.Text = "U ngarkua dhe u vulos dokumenti!";

                    Guid pdfFileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

                    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);
                    var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                    var wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(filePath);
                    var convertedFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                    wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(convertedFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Converted.Pdf");
                    Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/pdf");
                    Response.TransmitFile(convertedFilePath);
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                    File.Delete(convertedFilePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Nuk e keni zgjedhur dokumentin apo formati i dokumentit nuk pershtatet!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: didn't you ask this yesterday? but: there is no magic way to do this - Word documents are hugely different to PDF documents, so unless you're using a tool that has a "export as PDF" method (does `WordprocessingDocument` have that?), or access to a PDF printer driver (and "print" to that): this is very awkward. There is a related discussion on this exact topic [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf6c44dc-2a9b-4baf-96eb-5e4bd6e8594a/how-to-save-word-as-pdf-using-open-xml-sdk-20?forum=oxmlsdk) which suggests that there's no magic "export as pdf" method on that API

Comment: I have used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to convert word to pdf and it works. But I need to convert the byte array not the uploaded file to pdf, since i need to convert modified word to pdf

Comment: isn't `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` the "Word (application) automation" library? if so, that isn't supported on web-servers (AFAIK 
- happy to be corrected, but: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office), and it looks like your code is a web-server. There's no fundamental difference between a "byte array" and an "uploaded file", so if you have some code that works for one (supported or not): it should work for the other

Comment: Yes it works and it displays the word uploaded as PDF but in that document are not included paragraphs I added in that document. I need the word document to include them as PDF format. There is the code that modifies the word document and then tries to convert to PDF

Comment: can I clarify and restate? are you saying that the main problem here is that you're using an API to modify the data, but the modifications aren't showing? if so: surely all you need is to `File.WriteAllBytes(someTempPath, ms.ToArray())`, and load that? Currently your modifications are written to `Session["ByteArray"]`, but that is never used anywhere. It *looks* like any such `File.WriteAllBytes` should replace your `FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);` call

Comment: I am saying that I have uploaded a word doc which I modified(added text to it) and than that word I want to convert as PDF as modified. For the moment as it is only converts the word as I uploaded not the modified one,can you check the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, here you load the data from the `FileUploadControl` into session:

```
Session["ByteArray"] = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
```

You then load the data from session into a `MemoryStream` that you use to open the document for editing:

```
    byte[] byteArray = (byte[])(Session["ByteArray"]);
    if (byteArray != null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
```

At the end of this, after your edits, you copy the updated content back to session:

```
            lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf3);
            lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf4);
        }
        Session["ByteArray"] = ms.ToArray();
```

but; that's the last time we see session used; you then write the uploaded file to a temporary file, and use *that* to perform Word automation:

```
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);
var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(filePath);
```

So yes: this will convert the original file **as uploaded**, because `FileUploadControl` is unrelated to the changes you made. Instead, perhaps try:

```
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, (byte[])Session["ByteArray"]);
var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(filePath);
```

This should then include the changes.

---

Additional side observations:

- Word automation is unsupported and not recommended on web-servers; if it works for you: great, but just be aware that if it suddenly breaks you'll be on your own
- be careful that you're not leaving files scattered on disk, or lots of open Word instances / files; basically: check you're not "leaking" (`appWord`, `wordDoc`, `filePath`, `convertedFilePath` etc - all probably need some `finally` love)
- putting Word files into session-state (`Session`) *probably* isn't a good or necessary idea; I would recommend just using a local `byte[]` or similar throughout in this method, and remove `Session["ByteArray"]` *completely*

Comment: ERROR:We can’t save this file because it’s read-only. To keep your changes, you'll need to save the document with a new name or in a different location. I tried as you suggested me but it throws that error

Comment: @ArbenitaMusliu *where* do you get that error, exactly? is that in the `ExportAsFixedFormat` call?